# Ruby Routes Not Always In Same Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this in my `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :carts do
    collection do
      post :review
      post :charge
    end
end
```

Sometimes, when a user goes to `/carts/review`, instead of going to the `review` action, it instead tries to go to `show` with an `id` of `review`.  I've gotten this error 3 times in production, and successfully reviewed the cart dozens of times.  Any ideas on what might be happening?

This is Rails 3.2.1 running on Ubuntu 10.04 with ruby 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes only accept the `POST` method for `/carts/review`. A `GET` to `/carts/review` will be interpreted as `/carts/:id, :id => "review"` because there is no `GET` path for `/carts/review` specifically.